# Using DbContext in singleton when using NoTracking option

Tags: .net-core, dbcontext, ef-core-2.0

I have a singleton service in .NET core 2.2 that polls and performs CRUD operation based on a set frequency.  Every time it needs to perform an operation, it injects a `DbContext` by using a scope factory to get an instance of the `DbContext` which I figured was necessary to ensure that the context does not build up in size due to tracking all the CRUD operations over time.

However, is the size of the context still a valid concern if the default tracking behavior is set to `NoTracking`?  If a context is set to not track entities would it be ok to create the context once and assign it to a class property that gets reused for every CRUD without worrying about it growing over time within a singleton?

Comment: No, but then multi-threading may become an issue.

Comment: Oh yea...good point